# ResponseAdvice not getting triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspect

Plenty of question in SO but almost no working solution.

Just a simple implementation of ResponseAdvice with @ControllerAdvice

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@ReqeustMapping("/test")
class TestController{
   @RequestMapping( method=GET )
   public String test(){ return "Test"; }
}
```

**Advice**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ResponseDecorator implements ResponseBodyAdvice<String> {

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getParameterType().equals(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String beforeBodyWrite(String body,
                                  MethodParameter returnType,
                                  MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request,
                                  ServerHttpResponse response) {
      System.out.println ( "Just print this when before sending ");
     return body;
   }
}
```

The **beforeBodyWrite** does not trigger at all. The app is fully annotation driven. And both advice and controller are in same package. What am I missing!

Comment: If we look at Javadoc of ResponseBodyAdvice, there are specifics that may cause for your setup not to work. Back to basic, maybe can explore with returning ResponseEntity and using @@ControllerAdvice. I suspect you might need to change the controller annotation to @Controller too. Have not tried myself so I dont consider this as answer

Comment: Might be due to the spring boot version that you have. I tried the same with 
 Spring boot `v2.1.9.RELEASE` and it's working fine without any change.

Comment: @Jayr tried everything.. no change

Comment: @MadhuBhat tried with 2.1.9. Same.. not working. Do you mind sharing your code in github?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thanks. Actually i tried one separately and it works perfectly fine. Weird why my app is not working. Any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Silly mistake.The issue here  is the **supports** methods

```
  @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return returnType.getParameterType().equals(String.class);
    }
```

making this method return **TRUE** has fixed the issue.

```
  @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType,
                            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }
```

The supports method should return **true**. So adjust your logic based on your requirement.

Comment: This wouldn't be a fix, but a hack. Because this would make `ResponseDecorator` intercept EVERY method.

Comment: Its not a hack. The supports method should return true is the answer. Edited my answer

Comment: The reason why I say this is a hack is, the supports method override is to specify which methods should be intercepted by the advice. In case you simply return `true`, even methods where you might not want this to be intercepted would be intercepted by this. Anyhow as long as it serves your purpose, it should be fine, but in case you have methods you don't want this to be called, it'll still be called.